# Implicit conversion error to NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I have this relatively simple helper method:

```
- (float)imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float imageWidth = [[self.widthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
    float ratio = screenWidth/imageWidth;
    float imageHeight = ratio * [[self.heightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
    return imageHeight;
}
```

which works completely fine when called in another method but in this method:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat newWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat newHeight = [self imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight ));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

the compiler says:
`Implicit conversion from 'NSInteger' to 'NSIndexPath' is disallowed`

and I don't know why and how to fix this. Any idea?

Comment: Amazing that it doesn't identify the line in error!!

Comment: But very likely it's this line: `CGFloat newHeight = [self imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];`  (Chuck `.row`)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 methods:

1. `- (float)imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
2. `- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

each of which have a `NSIndexPath *` parameter.

Now, in `imageWithImage:forRowAtIndexPath:` you are calling `imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
[self imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]
```

and on that line you are taking the `row` from the `indexPath` (an `NSInteger`) and trying to pass it to `imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`:, which is expecting an `NSIndexPath *`.

This is the cause of the error, because the compiler knows to expect an `NSIndexPath *` and it knows that you are providing an `NSInteger`.

To solve, change the code to:

```
CGFloat newHeight = [self imageHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```